# Windows Phone 8: access UI Dispatcher in C++ code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I am working on an Windows Phone 8 Application that uses mixed C# for UI and C++ for the underlying backed.  I have some instances where I need to run some C++ code on the UI dispatcher thread (IE GetGeopositionAsync()).

I have tried a method of making a callback from C++ to C# that runs in the UI thread and then calls a C++ method and runs:

```
auto window = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
```

However this is returning null.  Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem some days ago, as it has always returned null. I ended up using in WinRT. According to MSDN ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationview.corewindow)) you should be able to use this in WP8 as well.

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow
```